# Create a bounce effect on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to develop a similar website like http://www.unlocknrepair.com/ 
In this website when you hover your mouse over the Unlocking or Phone repair button a dropdown menu appears. Is there a way to make this dropdown appear in bouncy way.. like I want it to bounce a bit before it stabilizes. It is possible in jQuery, but can it be done using only css and javascript?

Comment: jQuery is CSS & JavaScript.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Okie, I know that but I dont want to include jQuery now in my script coz I have almost written the whole code. What I meant was can it be done using CSS and javascript(the difficult way).

Comment: jQuery is a extension on javascript, @ShivanRaptor. _"Is it possible in jQuery or can it be done using only javascript"_  is a perfectly valid question. (Although it might have included the word "native")

Comment: @Cerbrus Well yeah, my bad!! But can it be done using only javascript?

Comment: Anything that can be done in jQuery can be done using native js. And in this case, it's not that much code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If experimental css3 is an option, you can do it even without javascript using css animations with the `@keyframes` rule.

```css
#parent {
    position:relative;
     height: 40px;
}

#onhover {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    
}

#parent:hover #onhover {
    display: block;
    top: 30px;
    animation:mymove 0.8s linear;
    -moz-animation:mymove 0.8s linear; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation:mymove 0.8s linear; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation:mymove 0.8s linear; /* Opera */
    -ms-animation:mymove 0.8s linear; /* IE */
}

@keyframes mymove
{
0%   {top:0px;}
10%  {top:3px;}
40%  {top:40px;}
60%  {top:25px;}
80%  {top:35px;}
100% {top:30px;}
}

@-moz-keyframes mymove /* Firefox */
{
0%   {top:0px;}
10%  {top:3px;}
40%  {top:40px;}
60%  {top:25px;}
80%  {top:35px;}
100% {top:30px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes mymove /* Safari and Chrome */
{
0%   {top:0px;}
10%  {top:3px;}
40%  {top:40px;}
60%  {top:25px;}
80%  {top:35px;}
100% {top:30px;}
}

@-o-keyframes mymove /* Opera */
{
0%   {top:0px;}
10%  {top:3px;}
40%  {top:40px;}
60%  {top:25px;}
80%  {top:35px;}
100% {top:30px;}
}

@-ms-keyframes mymove /* IE */
{
0%   {top:0px;}
10%  {top:3px;}
40%  {top:40px;}
60%  {top:25px;}
80%  {top:35px;}
100% {top:30px;}
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">hover me<div id="onhover">hovering</div></div>
```

Another "bounce" animation:

```js
$(function() {

$(document.body).delegate( "img", "mouseenter", function() {
    var $this = $(this).addClass("right");
    setTimeout(function() {
        $this.removeClass("right");
    }, 2000);
});
    
});
```

```css
body { font-size: .7em; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, "Liberation Sans", sans-serif; padding: 0 !important; }
img {
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease-in;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 1s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform 1s ease-in;
}
#anim.right {
    -moz-animation-name: bounce;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -moz-transform: translate(400px);
    -moz-transition: none;

    -webkit-animation-name: bounce;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate(400px);
    -webkit-transition: none;
}

@-moz-keyframes bounce {
  from {
    -moz-transform: translate(0px);
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: translate(400px);
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  73% {
    -moz-transform: translate(360px);
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  86% {
    -moz-transform: translate(400px);
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  93% {
    -moz-transform: translate(380px);
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: translate(400px);
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(400px);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  73% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(360px);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  86% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(400px);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  93% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(380px);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translate(400px);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="anim" src="http://hacks.mozilla.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/75px-Aurora210.png" width="75" height="75" />
```

See [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/@keyframes) for more details and browser compatibility.

Comment: Dude this was a great answer. I am displaying a menu on hover like in the website posted in the question. Can that be done using your method.

Comment: Like I am going from display:none to display:block on hover. So can the animation from the above jsFiddle be acheived on that.?

Comment: I've updated the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7TsWs/2/) so that the `#onhover` element goes from display:none to block.

Comment: U've been of great help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible using native javascript. [Take a look at this document](http://javascript.info/tutorial/animation#easeout)
Note, I'm linking to the "easeOut" section, since I think that represents a ball's bouncing a little better than their "bounce".
[Here's a good example, further down the same page.](http://javascript.info/tutorial/animation#highlighter_469157)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I'll have to spend a lot of time to study the whole thing. LOL. But Yeah I guess I'll do that. Thank you for the link. It will come in handy in fuure as well.

Comment: Yea, I'd suggest working through the document from the top, indeed.
Please mark this as an answer, if it is.

Comment: Let me get the solution first. If going through the document helps I'll mark it as an answer.