# Trying to make a link bounce on hover

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a link 'bounce' on hover. I've put this on an image and it works, however when I apply the same style of effect to a link it doesn't work.

CSS

```
.intro-websites:hover{
transform: translateY(-10px);
}
.intro-connect:hover{
transform: translateY(-10px);
}
.intro-ppc:hover{
transform: translateY(-10px);
}
.intro-display:hover{
transform: translateY(-10px);
}
```

HTML

```
<p>
<a class="intro-websites" style="text-decoration: none;" href="#">Websites</a>
<span style="color:#fedb00">&bull;</span>
<a class="intro-connect" style="text-decoration: none;" href="#">Connect</a> 
<span style="color:#fedb00">&bull;</span> 
<a class="intro-ppc" style="text-decoration: none;" href="#">Pay-Per-Click</a>
<span style="color:#fedb00">&bull;</span>
<a class="intro-display" style="text-decoration: none;" href="#">Display</a>
</p>
```

Can anyone help or point out where I'm going wrong? 
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a bounce effect on hover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13601169/create-a-bounce-effect-on-hover)

Comment: I only need to move the text not create additional text on hover. So it would just look like the text is bouncing.

Comment: why not use <div class="intro-websites"> to warp <a>

Comment: I think transform does not work for elements that have `display: inline;` which is the default for `a`. Also, your CSS can be more concise using `a[class*="intro-"]:hover{transform: translateY(-10px);}`.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the bouncing effect on hover the following code will help:

```
.intro-websites:hover {
   animation: bounce 2.5s infinite; //other browsers
   -webkit-animation: bounce 2.5s infinite; //webkit browsers
   -moz-animation: bounce 2.5s infinite; //firefox
   -o-animation: bounce 2.5s infinite; //opera
}
```

You now need to animate the bounce using CSS3 animations and keyframes:

```
//CSS3 Bounce Animation
@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
    0%,  
    100% {
       -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    } 
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes bounce {
    0%, 
    100% {
       -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    }
    50% {
       -moz-transform: translateY(-10px);
    }
}
@-o-keyframes bounce {
    0%,
    100% {
       -o-transform: translateY(0);
    }
    50% {
       -o-transform: translateY(-10px);
    }
}
@keyframes bounce {
    0%,  
    100% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    50% {
        transform: translateY(-10px);
    }
}
```

I have added the keyframe animation for webkit browsers, firefox, opera and others. If you don't need them all just remove the vendor prefixes in the hover styles and use the ones you want.

Comment: Thanks Neelam, however ive tried it and it still doesnt work:http://codepen.io/samallen/pen/ObRjzY

Comment: add `display: inline-block` to class `.intro-websites`

Comment: Opera now uses the webkit engine, so no need to include the -o- modifier anymore. Also, this should absolutely work. No idea why it isn't.

Comment: as @codeninja93 said you need to add display: inline-block to the link class like so before the hover: `.intro-websites { display:inline-block; }` and it will work. Links are not block level elements and this needs to be specified.

Comment: `//CSS3 Bounce Animation` the comments are also invalid use `/* comment */ `

Answer (score 1):

add `display: inline-block;` to your `a` tags.

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.bounce:hover {
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}
```

```html
<p>
  <a class="intro-websites bounce" href="#">Websites</a>
  <span style="color:#fedb00">&bull;</span>
  <a class="intro-connect bounce" href="#">Connect</a> 
  <span style="color:#fedb00">&bull;</span> 
  <a class="intro-ppc bounce" href="#">Pay-Per-Click</a>
  <span style="color:#fedb00">&bull;</span>
  <a class="intro-display bounce" href="#">Display</a>
</p>
```

Comment: @SamAllen I have done some code optimization for you .. check the edited version

Answer (score 1):

This should help you get started. If you need an animation rather than a one-time transition, go with Neelam's solution.

```css
a[class*="intro-"] {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease;
}
a[class*="intro-"]:hover {
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}
```

```html
<p>
  <a class="intro-websites" style="text-decoration: none;" href="#">Websites</a>
  <span style="color:#fedb00">&bull;</span>
  <a class="intro-connect" style="text-decoration: none;" href="#">Connect</a> 
  <span style="color:#fedb00">&bull;</span> 
  <a class="intro-ppc" style="text-decoration: none;" href="#">Pay-Per-Click</a>
  <span style="color:#fedb00">&bull;</span>
  <a class="intro-display" style="text-decoration: none;" href="#">Display</a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than animating the y coordinate I'd recommend to use in this case `padding-bottom` instead, which has not only the same effect as the above one, you could also prevent the links from that jumping which sometimes is happening when you are hovering the links.

You could achieve this with the following code

**HTML**

```
<nav>
  <a href="">Websites</a>
  <a href="">Connect</a>
  <a href="">Pay-Per-Click</a>
  <a href="">Display</a>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #eee;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: 0.2s;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

a:hover {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #eee;
  text-align: center;
}
a {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: 0.2s;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
a:hover {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="">Websites</a>
  <a href="">Connect</a>
  <a href="">Pay-Per-Click</a>
  <a href="">Display</a>
</nav>
```